# Can't set full image in Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I can't set full image in navigation bar (or navigation controller ,in the top of app). there will be little space remaining in the left.And when I put info button it's not on the image. How can I fix it

here is my code,pls take a look

```
UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerBG.png"]];
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    self.navigationItem.titleView =img;
    [img release];


UIButton * infoDarkButtonType = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
     infoDarkButtonType.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0);
     infoDarkButtonType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [infoDarkButtonType addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoDarkButtonType];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = infoButton;
     [infoDarkButtonType release];
     [infoButton release];
```

very thank you.

Me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the navigation bar to show an image cant you try this

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"custom_nav_bar.png"];
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Comment: YEP It can work but it change all nav bar every page.I just wanna change 1 page.Could u guide me more please.

Comment: Can you hide the navigation bar and use a custom view similar to the navigation bar with the necessary buttons instead.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm afraid it can't. Cause It from navigation controller

Comment: Yes just hide the navigation bar. It is possible.

Comment: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];`

Comment: Yep I can Hide it. thank and now I should create imageview and put it in top of view like navigationbar right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line ot add image in NavigationController...

```
UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerBG.png"]];
img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
[self.navigationController.navigationItem addSubView:img];
[img release];
```

now, you set image in Navigation..